# Can non-default SMS app ALWAYS receive broadcast when SMS received, even when force closed?

Tags: android, sms, android-broadcastreceiver

So I have followed this [guideline](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87) to show a simple toast when SMS is received. While it works ok when app is running, when I go to settings and force-close the app, it stops working.

I checked many answers here on StackOverflow for simmilar questions, but none actually answers whether (and how) it is possible to make a piece of code execute EVERY time SMS is received, without the app being set as the default SMS app on device (Android 4.4+). Is it?

Consider that even service can be stopped, and when that happens, service is not a solution anymore.

I am interested in API level 19+

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, this isn't really possible without your app being the default SMS app.

When the user forcibly closes your app, it is put back into the *stopped* state, and a statically registered Receiver for the implicit `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast won't work until your app has been explicitly started again; e.g., by the user launching your app from an explicit launcher shortcut.

The default SMS app, on the other hand, will be delivered the `SMS_DELIVER` broadcast, and that is explicit. Even if the default has been forcibly stopped, that broadcast will act like any other explicit starting `Intent` to bring it out of the *stopped* state.

If timeliness isn't a major concern, you could just query the SMS Provider as needed – e.g., at each startup – and determine if you've missed any new messages since last checked.

Answer (score 0):

I was making an SMS app. The broadcast would not work when was closed. Tried many things but it didn't work out. Then I decided to change it to the default SMS app by the old code, then the app splash keeps restarting. Then, when I used the following code but it was not working. The dialog box would not show. Then, I found a answer on StackOverflow. Basically you need one activity, TWO receivers and one service. when I added all that to manifest. The default SMS dialog was shown in the app. Which was a success. then I closed the app. my app was receiving the broadcast even when closed. So everything works out pretty well in the end. I hope my experience will help you.

Here is the link [How do I set my app as the default SMS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127564/how-do-i-set-my-app-as-the-default-sms-app)

```
    void defaultSmsApp(){
    RoleManager roleManager;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        roleManager = getApplicationContext().getSystemService(RoleManager.class);
        if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {
            Log.e(TAG, "defaultSmsApp: " );
            if (roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PrismApp set as default.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOT DEFAULT.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent roleRequestIntent = roleManager . createRequestRoleIntent (
                        RoleManager.ROLE_SMS);
                 someActivityResultLauncher.launch(roleRequestIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}


ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    Intent data = result.getData();

                }
            }
        });
```