# Developing android messages and contacts backup/restore app without root?

Tags: android, backup, android-contacts, restore, message

I am working on android application (as a final year project in my university) which backup and restores contacts, messages, calendar, call logs etc. I started working on it yesterday and until now I am able to get the message conversations through ContentResolver like this:

```
private void MsgBackup(){
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};

        Cursor SMSL = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int msgscount = SMSL.getCount();
        msgs = new String[SMSL.getCount()][2];
        int i = 0;
        while (SMSL.moveToNext()) {
            address = SMSL.getString(SMSL.getColumnIndex("address"));
            body = SMSL.getString(SMSL.getColumnIndex("body"));

            msgs[i][0] = address;
            msgs[i][1] = body;

            i++;
        }
        SMSL.close();
//will do something here to backups msgs array


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error Fetching messages, check permissions!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

What I am worried about is "Restoring them". I read somewhere that it is not possible to restore messages without root access. If so, then how come the applications in the market do this job without root access?

Comment: Since KitKat (4.4), only the app that is selected as the user's default messaging app has write access to the message Provider. The current recommendation for backup/restore apps is to configure them to allow the user to temporarily set your app as the default for a restore, then switch back to the previous default. [This blog page](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1) has the details and recommended workflow. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30133663) might also be of some help, as it lists the minimums required to be a default.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for your reply and help. I am working according to your recommendation and I will post the result here as soon as I am finished.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you. I have completed work in messages backup and restore. But I have little problem that I need help with. I posted this question here but no one answered. Have a look at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41305513/restoring-backed-up-messages-conversations-times-are-incorrect