# Restoring backed up messages, conversations times are incorrect

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which backs up and restores the messages/conversations from device. It backup the messages, export file in the form of xml, and then later restore it. The only problem I am facing is the date/times of conversations. It is changed to current time at the time of restoration, but when I open any conversation, there time is correct. Have a look at photos.

Before backup:

[image]

After backup:

[image]

Code I am using for backup:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

        final String[] projection = new String[]{"*"};

        Cursor SMSL = contentResolver.query(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        int msgscount = SMSL.getCount();
        if (msgscount>0) {
            msgs = new String[SMSL.getCount()][5];
            int i = 0;
            while (SMSL.moveToNext()) {
                address = SMSL.getString(SMSL.getColumnIndex("address"));
                body = SMSL.getString(SMSL.getColumnIndex("body"));
                read = SMSL.getString(SMSL.getColumnIndex("read"));
                date = SMSL.getString(SMSL.getColumnIndex("date"));
                type = SMSL.getString(SMSL.getColumnIndex("type"));

                msgs[i][0] = address;
                msgs[i][1] = body;
                msgs[i][2] = date;
                msgs[i][3] = read;
                msgs[i][4] = type;

                Log.i("Date: ", String.valueOf(SMSL.getLong(SMSL.getColumnIndex("date"))));

                i++;
            }
            SMSL.close();
        }else{
            msgs = new String[0][0];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No messages found!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Code for restoring:

```
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
                    //Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    for (int i = 0; i < readMsgsFromFile.length; i++) {
                        values.put("address",readMsgsFromFile[i][0]);
                        values.put("body",readMsgsFromFile[i][1]);
                        values.put("date",readMsgsFromFile[i][2]);
                        values.put("read",readMsgsFromFile[i][3]);
                        values.put("type",readMsgsFromFile[i][4]);

                        contentResolver.insert(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, values);
                        Log.i("Restoring: ",readMsgsFromFile[i][2]);
                    }
```

Comment: Someone please correct me if my question is wrong instead of voting down. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I'm guessing that the conversation table is simply updated with the current time whenever a new message is written in a given thread. You might have to figure the most recent message yourself, and directly modify the date on the conversation accordingly. I'll have a look later on, if I get some time.

Comment: @MikeM. the problem is that we cannot modify or get the date/time of conversations, although there is column of date in threads table (I saw it from sqlite db file somewhere from android system folder). Through android `contentresolver`, we can only get/modify/insert three columns from threads table which are `_ID`, `SNIPPET` and `_COUNT`. Check my answer also.

Comment: Just got a chance to have a look into this. FWIW, I had no problem reading and updating the `"date"` column in the `threads` table. Also, I was unable to reproduce your described problem. That is, the date was always correct after restoring. I'm still trying to figure out what might be the issue in your case, but it might just be down to a minor implementation difference. I would mention, though, that the default SMS app is writing via a `ContentResolver`, too, so that's likely not the problem. Anyhoo, your workaround seems pretty solid, and it's rather clever. Nice job.

Comment: may be there is API difference. I am working on API 22 and 23. And yes only default SMS app can write messages through `ContentResolver` and that is not the issue. Where I suspect the issue is in this line `Log.i("Deleting ",mid); getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI+"/"+mid),null,null);` This line delete the temporary message. If I provide the  variable `mid` in where clause of `getContentResolver` (which currently is null) then conversations times are still incorrect. May I have to restore message in similar way. I will test and tell you.

Comment: I was referring to your answer - "But in case of writing messages through `contentresolver` query it does not work". Your regular SMS app is reading/writing the messages via `ContentResolver` whenever they're sent or received, so it's not simply the use of `ContentResolver` in and of itself that's the issue. That's what I meant, there. Anyhoo, I tried so many different query and write scenarios when I was testing, and I never could get an incorrect date/time for a conversation. I might play around with it some more later on, but I'm not sure if I'll find out anything more on my end.

Comment: in which API you are testing?

Comment: I tested on API 19 and 23 devices. I have to admit, though, that I didn't really test your posted code exactly. I just wrote my own tests. When I get back to it, first thing I'll do is a straight copy/paste from your post. Maybe some little quirk I'm just not seeing. Are you using emulators, or actual devices?

Comment: I tested on both actual and emulators.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mike M. I did find a solution and you are right, the conversation table is updated whenever a new message is received or sent by a user and the time of conversation is same as that message's (whether received or sent) time. But in case of writing messages through `contentresolver` query it does not work and the conversation time is current time at the time of writing. So what I did is add a temporary message in all of the conversations, right after messages are restored. And after that delete all the temporary messages, this will update the conversations time to last message time.

```
            HashSet hs = new HashSet();

            hs.addAll(list); 
//list is the ArrayList<String> which contains the addressess of all the messages and 
//through hashset we remove all the duplicates to get only the addressess once and hence we know the number of conversations and their addressess.

            list.clear();
            list.addAll(hs);
             //Add some dummy message to each conversation
            ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                values2.put("address",list.get(i));
                values2.put("date_sent",readMsgsFromFile[0][1]);
                values2.put("date",readMsgsFromFile[0][2]);
                values2.put("type",readMsgsFromFile[0][3]);
                values2.put("body","temp"); //this should be more unique
                values2.put("read",readMsgsFromFile[0][5]);
                values2.put("service_center","01010101");

                contentResolver.insert(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, values2);
            }

//Now deleting that message with body 'temp' from each conversation
            Cursor c = contentResolver.query(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
            while (c.moveToNext()){
                String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("body"));
                String mid = c.getString(0);
                if (body.equals("temp")){
                    Log.i("Deleting ",mid);
                    getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI+"/"+mid),null,null);
                }
            }
            c.close();
```

This word 'temp' could be and should be more unique so that it is not mixed with actual message.