# From a contact view, how to send a contact number to my sms app, to send an sms to it

Tags: android, sms, contacts

I've built an sms app wich support all features for sms activities(only sms). But now, my problem is that when my app is already the default one for sms, I can't get the number from contact view when I'd like to send sms to it through my app. Here are images to explain what I'd like to achieve.! [When I click to the sms icon,my app is opened by I can't get the number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uR9yS.png)
I do not have any code to handle the action SEND/SENDTO in my activity, but I just mentioned the intent-filter:action.SEND, action.SENDTO in the manifest file, as it is obligatory if we want to make the app selectable as the default sms app. I thought that the number from the contact view is accessed from the onActivityResult but it seems to not work, please help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the code for your `Activity` which handles the `SEND`/`SENDTO` actions, and explain exactly what problems you're having in retrieving the phone number/contact ID.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question. As I explain in my question, I have not any code to handle the data from the contact, could you suggest me one or just an helpful link?

Comment: Yeah, the number is going to be attached to the `Intent` used to start your `Activity`. The `onActivityResult()` method doesn't come into play for this. Gimme a minute, and I'll put together an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, so I'm waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When getting a `SENDTO` from Contacts, the number - possibly multiple numbers - will be attached as the data `Uri` on the `Intent` that started your `Activity`. When initializing your `Activity`, check for the appropriate action, and retrieve the number(s) if necessary.

For a basic example:

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SENDTO.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    String numbers = data.getSchemeSpecificPart();
}
```

For a more solid implementation, it would be prudent to strip any additional parameters that might be on the `Uri`, and to replace any non-Latin digits.

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SENDTO.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    String numbers = data.getSchemeSpecificPart();

    // Strip any extraneous parameters
    int i = numbers.indexOf('?');
    numbers = (i == -1) ? numbers : numbers.substring(0, i);

    // Replace non-Latin digits, and ensure our delimiter is something we expect
    numbers = PhoneNumberUtils.replaceUnicodeDigits(numbers).replace(",", ";");
    ...
}
```

If multiple numbers are received, they should come in a comma- or semicolon-delimited `String`. The above replaces commas with semicolons, so we don't need to worry later about which was used. You can then simply `split()` the `numbers` to get the individual numbers, should you've received more than one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll make a try with this and let you know the result. It's really the kind of code I need

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow, btw. Cheers!