# How to make my app become an option for sending text/message in contact details?

Tags: android, messaging

I want to add my app as option to contact people like whatsapp in the picture below :
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127564/android-default-making-default-sms-app

Comment: thank you  @Nilu i will check this  now