# Default SMS setup for Android Q and above

Tags: android, android-intent, smsmanager

I was able to set the app as a default messaging app with the below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,
                    getPackageName());
            startActivityForResult(intent, SET_AS_DEFAULT_INTENT);
```

But this works only on API <= 28 (Android 9 or below)

But this is not working on Android 10 or above.

Am I missing something? I heard about using a role manager but it is not working for me.

```
RoleManager roleManager = getSystemService(RoleManager.class);

            if (roleManager.isRoleAvailable(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {
                if (roleManager.isRoleHeld(RoleManager.ROLE_SMS)) {

                } else {
                    Intent roleRequestIntent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(
                            RoleManager.ROLE_SMS);
                    startActivityForResult(roleRequestIntent, SET_AS_DEFAULT_INTENT);
                }
            }
```

Comment: So `RoleManager` is working for you or not?

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Which specific versions are you having the problem on? API level 28 is Pie, Android 9, so I'm not sure exactly what you mean by these two statements: "But this works only on API <= 28 (Android 8 or below)", "But this is not working on Android 9 or above.", especially since the title specifies Android Q. Also, what happens when it doesn't work? Is it crashing?

Comment: @MikeM. sorry for the confusion I edited that now. The problem is with Android 10 and above only. It works on Android 9 and below.

Comment: @SaurabhThorat Oops, I made a lot of typo in the question and I corrected them now, sorry for that.

Comment: OK, yeah, if you're targeting 30, then you need to use the `RoleManager` method instead. Your code works for me, however, in my quick test project. Is your app listed in the available default app list on the Q device?

Comment: Yes, it is showing in the list but no dialog appears inside of the app to select.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Here's what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoszU.jpg. At this point, all I could suggest is to make sure that it's actually getting to the `startActivityForResult()` call. That is, make sure that those `if` conditions are true. I'll see if I can figure out how to get the behavior you're observing.

Comment: Did you added anything on the manifest?

Comment: Yeah, just what's needed for the app to qualify as an eligible default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30133663.

Comment: Voila, added those things in AndroidManifest and worked. Thanks a lot, mate.

Comment: I literally just started a new project, made sure the `targetSdkVersion` is 30, and copied/pasted that linked manifest, and your code into it.

Comment: Oh, was that it? Just missing some manifest entries?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working. Cheers!