# How to set Flutter app as default SMS app?

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, sms, flutter-dependencies

I want to make custom SMS app and for that purpose it should be default SMS app. In android we use this code to make app as default SMS app.

```
 Intent intent =   new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                    intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, 
                            myPackageName);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

Can somebody help how to achieve this in Flutter.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a method channel

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.chat/chat"

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "setDefaultSms") {
                try {
                    var intent = Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                    intent.putExtra(
                            Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,
                            <the app package name>
                    );
                    startActivity(intent);
                    result.success("Success")
                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Setting default sms.", null)
                }
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

after that in your dart code call the method channel

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel("com.example.chat/chat");
  try {
      final result = await platform.invokeMethod('setDefaultSms');
      print("Result: $result");
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
  }
```

Note the above solution won't make your app qualify to a default SMS app
You may need to add something to your manifest file for more info check out this post [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127564/how-do-i-set-my-app-as-the-default-sms-app)

Comment: Also, check out this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/telephony