# Android- How can Make my app as Default SMS App?

Tags: android, sms, backup

I am working an **SMS Backup** app which stores all **SIM** SMS in an xml file then we can restore back, then proplem is when i want restore it needs to make my APP as **Default SMS app**, I Have tried all the solutions but didn't worked for me... i used this but all in vain e.g:
**Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, myPackageName);
startActivity(intent);**

My App is not showing in **Select Default popup**. Please Help.

Comment: You need to satisfy all requirements in your manifest, otherwise your app will not be eligible to become default SMS app. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127564/how-do-i-set-my-app-as-the-default-sms-app

Comment: Thanks a lot. it solved... i was mising .MmsReceiver

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and its working fine for android 10 and 11

make sure to implement all requirements as per this : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

and Put following in your Mainactivity class

```
public void perm2(){
        Context mContext3 = getApplicationContext();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            RoleManager roleManager = null;
            roleManager = mContext3.getSystemService(RoleManager.class);
            Intent roleRequestIntent = roleManager.createRequestRoleIntent(
                    RoleManager.ROLE_SMS);
            startActivityForResult(roleRequestIntent, MESSAGE_CODE);

        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME,
                    mContext3.getPackageName());
            startActivityForResult(intent, MESSAGE_CODE);
        }

    }
```