# Android: How to get app to appear in list of default apps?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-sms

So for some reason my mum's tablet (WiFi only) has a constant notification that says it needs to have a default SMS app set, but because it has no SIM card (let alone a slot), SMS apps in the Play Store are marked as not compatible.

I've been throwing my (fairly amateur) Android dev skills at it and I can create a basic stub app that exists only to be set as a default SMS app.

My problem is that while I've figured out how (in the manifest) to let it have the SMS permission, I haven't been able to get it to be in the list of default apps. I've tried what's probably every way except the correct one to set things up in the manifest, and I created an activity with a basic UI (just a button) to bring up the option to set it, but nothing happens.

So basically... I'd really love it if someone could give me a few points in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30133663.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, that did it. I guess that was the one combination of a manifest file that worked, because I'm sure I tried all the others (including something similar to that I found on the Android developers website.