# Not able to set app as default sms app on android

Tags: android, react-native, gradlew

I created an app 'TestSMS' using react-native cli for android and built it using ./gradlew assembleRelease. Then copied the apk to whatsapp and installed the app from whatsapp in my android phone.

I have added the following permissions in androidmanifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

I am able to launch 'TestSMS' app in my phone and use it. I want to set 'TestSMS' app as default SMS app on my phone, but I cannot find 'TestSMS' in the installed app list when I go to Settings> Apps and Notifications > Default apps > SMS app. Neither I can see 'TestSMS' in Settings > Installed Apps.

I am new to react native and I might have missed a very crucial step. I would highly appreciate if someone can point out the mistake.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: The permissions don't really do or indicate anything on their own. There are specific components that you must list in your manifest to be able to show as a default SMS app candidate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30133663.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike, it solved my problem when I added those components in manifest. Really appreciate your help.