# How to block an sms sender in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I wrote a Java application using Blocked Number Contract, but it crashes. I don't understand how to use the application as the default application. I have an application for detecting spam in incoming SMS, it reads the last SMS, outputs it and makes a prediction. How can I block the sender's number of this sms? I use Blocked Number Contract, but I can't. How to do set application as default correctly. Or are there other blocking methods? Please help me!

**A piece of code from MainActivity.java**

```
 if (phone_number.contains("+7")) {
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            String url_ad = String.format("https://get-region-by-number.herokuapp.com/get_region/%1$s", phone_number);
            myTextView6.setText("Регион отправителя:");

            client.get(url_ad, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                    myTextView5.setText("");
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                    myTextView5.setText(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(responseString.replaceAll("\"", "")));

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); // there 's a crash
                    values.put(BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NUMBER, "12345@abdcde.com"); // there 's a crash
                    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(BlockedNumberContract.BlockedNumbers.CONTENT_URI, values); // there 's a crash

                }
            });
        }

 private boolean checkDefaultSettings() {

        boolean isDefault = false;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

            if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(this).equals(getPackageName())) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("This app is not set as your default messaging app. Do you want to set it as default?")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            }
                        })
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @TargetApi(19)
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
                                intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, getPackageName());
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        });
                builder.show();

                isDefault = false;
            } else
                isDefault = true;
        }
        return isDefault;
    }


    private String isMyAppLauncherDefault() {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

        List<IntentFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
        filters.add(filter);
        final String myPackageName = getPackageName();
        List<ComponentName> activities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
        final PackageManager packageManager = (PackageManager) getPackageManager();

        packageManager.getPreferredActivities(filters, activities, null);
        for (ComponentName activity : activities) {
            if (myPackageName.equals(activity.getPackageName())) {
                return "1";
            }
        }
        return "0";

    }
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.mysmsapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="SPAM Detector"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MySMSApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/face">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: have you got the permission access to sms read or write

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, unless your app is the default SMS app, or the default phone app, you don't really have access to `BlockedNumberContract`. Also, unless your app is a full-blown messaging client, then it should _not_ be set as the default SMS app, which is responsible for many things, like receiving and processing all incoming messages (not just SMS, but also MMS, RCS, etc.), managing storage for all messages, posting notifications, etc. If you really want to try it out, though, here's how to get your app set up to be eligible to be the default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30133663.

Comment: @Amitpandey
```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: @MikeM. OK, thank you, are there any other blocking methods besides BlockedNumberContract?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry.