# SMS Broadcast Receiver not working when application is not running

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I registered a broadcast receiver in my manifest like this :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="9999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And my SMSReceiver class like this :

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if     (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
...
```

But the code in the onReceive method is never called. I've tried without the android:exported and android:permission tags in the receiver, but nothing works.

Comment: Did you launch `MainActivity` at least once after installation to bring the app out of the stopped state? Also, remove `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"` from the `<receiver>` element.

Comment: Yes I did. Then I kill the app with the android task manager

Comment: Then that is most likely forcibly stopping your app, and putting it back into the stopped state. Your Receiver won't work again until the you launch the app again.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed, you want to change that permission to `BROADCAST_SMS` instead, since you don't have that one specified.

Comment: Still not working :(

Comment: `telephony` needs to be capitalized in the `<receiver>`'s `<action>`. That is, `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`. Sorry, I would've noticed earlier, but I thought your title meant that it _did_ work when the app was running.

Comment: I have the same problem. When the app is running, SmsReceiver is triggered and working normal. But when the app is not running (the screen is off), SmsReceiver is not triggered.

Comment: I have the same problem as @Plugie When the app is running, SmsReceiver is triggered and working normal. But when the app is not running SmsReceiver is not triggered

Answer (score 0):

Add `RECEIVE_SMS` permission along with `READ_SMS`.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, 
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS_RECEIVE);
```

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

Since android 4.4 you have to implement some feature to change your sms app to the default sms app and getSms/MMS. And only the default app get sms's/mms's notification.

This answer can help you to do that : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720657/how-to-set-my-sms-app-default-in-android-kitkat)

Comment: This is not correct. Since 4.4, the `SMS_RECEIVED` action is still broadcast, and it cannot be aborted. Any app registered for that broadcast can receive it.