# My app don't appear in Default SMS app

Tags: android, sms

Why my app don't appear in Default SMS app?

**Manifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cyber_dove.MessaGen"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.cyber_dove.MessaGen.sms.ACTION_SENDTO" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.cyber_dove.MessaGen.sms.ACTION_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.cyber_dove.MessaGen.sms.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER_ACTION"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.cyber_dove.MessaGen.sms.SMS_DELIVER_ACTION"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />

                <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I want to show my app in default sms box in settings
Please help me
Becuase i can't delete an message from sent message only if my app selected a default sms app???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720657/how-to-set-my-sms-app-default-in-android-kitkat

Comment: It's not work for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `<data>` element from the SMS Receiver's `<intent-filter>`.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.cyber_dove.MessaGen.sms.SMS_DELIVER_ACTION"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And you're missing the `<intent-filter>` tags in the composing Activity.

```
<activity android:name="com.cyber_dove.MessaGen.sms.ACTION_SENDTO" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="sms" />
        <data android:scheme="smsto" />
        <data android:scheme="mms" />
        <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: You are just epic bro .I stayed in this for month .You never know whats missing .IDE doesn't tell you.