# How to open settings onClick?

Tags: android

I want to go to the settings where you can change default apps (launcher, browser, music player) I have tried this -

```
public void setdef(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(
    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS));
}
```

but why does it say "**ACTION_MANAGE_DEFAULT_APPS_SETTINGS cannot be resolved or is not a field**"

I got the string [from here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)

Comment: what is your android version because this is only for API 24 or above

Comment: o wtf why would they not have this in previous android versions? Is there any solution for api 11+ ? I just want to set my app as default browser onclick

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822101/how-to-programmatically-open-the-permission-screen-for-a-specific-app-on-android) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421527/how-can-i-start-android-application-info-screen-programmatically)

Comment: no, I think I need this but for browser instead ( also my seconds question is the same)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720657/how-to-set-my-sms-app-default-in-android-kitkat