# Can I still delete sms from android inbox in the latest version?

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, sms

I want to delete sms from android inbox when I receive it in my app. I already researched stackoverflow and found the codes but it doesn't work. I am not sure this is because I am using the latest android, gradle and emulator.

```
    private fun deleteSMS(message: String, number: String): Boolean {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "Deleting SMS from inbox")

            val uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox")
            val c = this.contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
            c?.let {
                if(!it.moveToFirst()) {
                    it.close()
                    return false
                }

                do {
                    val id = it.getInt(0)
                    val threadId = it.getInt(1)
                    val address = it.getString(2)
                    val body = it.getString(5)

                    Log.d(TAG, "address, body: $address : $body")
                    this.contentResolver.delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/$id"), null, null)
                }while (it.moveToNext())
            }

            c?.close()
            return true
        }catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.message)
            return false
        }
    }
```

I tried this code in java but it also doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: You can only write/delete to `content://sms/` if your app is selected as the default sms app

Comment: Can I make my app as the default app? If then, could you let me know how to do that?

Comment: you don't want to do that unless your app is supposed to handle all incoming/outgoing SMSes and MMSes - that is it has to be fully fledged messaging app. If it is you can follow tips from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720657/how-to-set-my-sms-app-default-in-android-kitkat

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, deleting SMS messages like that is no longer possible since Android 4.4 (KitKat), unless your app is the default SMS app or the device is rooted.

> Also, the system now allows only the default app to write message data to the provider, although other apps can read at any time.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/kitkat.html

If you try anyway, it silently fails - it won't delete anything, won't raise any exceptions and won't display error messages.

If you only intend to target 4.4 in your app, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697282/android-kitkat-api-19-how-to-write-messages-in-sms-content-provider-without/27709655) workaround might help, but it won't work in later versions.

Comment: Isn't any way to make my app as the default app?

Comment: You can set it under Settings > Apps & notifications > Default apps. 

On KitKat, you can find it in the top right menu (the three dots)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. BTW, can you let me know in detail? I didn't what I need under Settings>Apps & notifications>Default apps